# what is the best way to run chef-client in specific intervals

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

Currently I am using open source chef and having number of nodes chef client is installed. I want the chef client to run in specific intervals. Any good cookbooks out there to configure it.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the [official chef-client cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/chef-client).

That's precisely one of the main points of using this cookbook.

If you just include the `chef-client::default` on your nodes' run_lists, it's going to run every 30 minutes. If you want something different, it's just a matter of adjusting `node["chef_client"]["interval"]` -- note that this is in seconds, and the default is 1800.

The cookbook's readme file lists all tuneable attributes.

Comment: if not mentored  any of these `chef-client::default`  & `node["chef_client"]["interval"]` . Then what will be the interval ?

Answer (score 1):

The Chef [client.rb file](https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_client.html) exposes the interval attribute:

`interval   The frequency (in seconds) at which the chef-client runs. Default value: 1800.`

Answer (score -2):

Would it not be a good fit to use something like cron or Windows Task Scheduler for this?

Comment: The chef-client cookbook has those options too.